# How to access controller that has parameter in constructor

Tags: laravel-5.3

My Project structure

Laravel

- App

  - Customfolder

    - Customfolder1

      - Customfolder2

        - CountryInterface
  - Http

    - Controllers

      - RegisterController.php
- bootstrap
- config
- database
- public

Following is RegisterController.php code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Customfolder\Customfolder1\Customfolder2\CountryInterface; 

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
     public function __construct(CountryInterface $country)
     {
           $this->country = $country;
     }

     public function postSignup(){

     }
}
```

From my signup form, I am getting user data like name, complete address, email, phone etc and It will come to postSignup function.

When I submit signup form then It gives me following error.

```
Class Customfolder\Customfolder1\Customfolder2\CountryInterface does not exist
```

Following is my route

Route::any('/signup','RegisterController@postSignup');

Following is my interface code

```
namespace Customfolder\Customfolder1\Customfolder2;

interface CountryInterface
{
}
```

My confusion is how to call controller when constructor has some arguments and secondly, what can be the reason of above mentioned error and possible solutions?

Comment: Show your `CountryInterface` class.

Comment: I have edited question and mentioned interface code

Comment: The interfaces are not instantiable while building the classes,  read more about it in docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations

Comment: where I am instantiating it? I have read link that you have provided and there they have passed "EventPusher $pusher" to constructor

Comment: You are also passing `CountryInterface` in the constructor and Laravel tries to initiate it. You should bind it to some class as described in the link.

Comment: Actually my this same concept was already working in laravel 4.2 but When I am trying to use same in laravel 5.3 It is giving error